# Nested Java enum definition - does declaring as static make a difference?

Tags: java, enums, class-design

I have an interface - here's a nicely contrived version as an example:

```
public interface Particle {

    enum Charge {
        POSITIVE, NEGATIVE
    }

    Charge getCharge();

    double getMass();

    etc...
}
```

Is there any difference in how implementations of this would behave if I defined the `Charge` enum as static - i.e. does this have any effect:

```
public interface Particle {

    static enum Charge {
        POSITIVE, NEGATIVE
    }

    Charge getCharge();

    double getMass();

    etc...
}
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

No, it makes no difference. However the reason is not because it is a member declaration inside an interface, as Jon says. The real reason is according to language spec (**8.9**) that

> Nested enum types are implicitly
>   static. It is permissable to
>   explicitly declare a nested enum type
>   to be static.

At the following example static does not make any difference either (even though we have no interface):

```
public class A {
  enum E {A,B};
}

public class A {
  static enum E {A,B};
}
```

Another example with a nested **private** enum (not implicitly public).

```
public class A {
  private static enum E {A,B}
}
```

Comment: I'd argue that it's both - it's implicitly static for two different reasons, but either of them would have been enough on its own.

Answer (score 31):

No, it makes no difference. From the [language spec, section 9.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.5):

> Interfaces may contain member type
>   declarations ([§8.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5)). A member type
>   declaration in an interface is
>   implicitly `static` and `public`.

Comment: yes (+1) and actually checkstyle would flag the 'static' as being redundant and would ask you to remove it. Variables in interfaces and annotations are automatically public, static and final, so these modifiers are redundant as well.