# using inner classes in Java - enum

Tags: java, enums, inner-classes

I have a very specific issue that has to do with an inner class. Let me show you some sample code:

```
class Foo {
    MYOPTIONS temp;

    public static enum MYOPTIONS {
        OPTION1, OPTION2, OPTION3;
    } 
}
```

So this enumeration is inside the class Foo. Now what I want to do is set the temp variable as one of the three options, but do that outside the class Foo, let's say from a class called External. Unfortunately I cannot have a set method to do that because `External.setTemp (MYOPTIONS.OPTION1)` is not valid, as the enum is not visible in class external.
So the only thing I could come up with is have three methods in class Foo:

```
public void setTempOption1 () {this.temp=MYOPTIONS.OPTION1;}
public void setTempOption2 () {this.temp=MYOPTIONS.OPTION2;}
public void setTempOption3 () {this.temp=MYOPTIONS.OPTION3;}
```

Obviously the other option is to change the enumeration and not have it as an inner class.
Are there any other options that I am missing?
Thanks

Comment: you don't need to change the enumeration, you just need to make the inner class (Foo) not-inner

Comment: Scoping does not work in the opposite direction.  If you declare a variable in a method, you don't expect it to be defined outside of the method.  It's the same concept, just in a more abstract way.

Comment: if you're using eclipse, there are refactoring tools that can automatically move the enum or the class to it's own file and make them public or package-private

Comment: Foo is not an inner class, MYOPTIONS is and I have no clue why I wrote it with caps :P Seems like I don't have another choice other than the 2 I suggested myself.

Comment: OPTION 2 has a blank too much, needs a comma, and OPTION3 a semicolon. Showing the test code and using correct indentation would be nice.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html - The Static Nested Classes part

Comment: the semicolon is optional in the end! still 2 typos in there :(

Comment: Note: All enums are static in Java, no need to declare that.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
class ContainsInnerEnum {
    MYOPTIONS temp;

    public enum MYOPTIONS {
        OPTION1, OPTION2, OPTION3;
    } 
}

class EnumTester {
    public void test () {
        ContainsInnerEnum ie = new ContainsInnerEnum ();
        // fail:
        // ie.temp = MYOPTIONS.OPTION1;
        // works:
        ie.temp = ContainsInnerEnum.MYOPTIONS.OPTION1;
    }       
}
```

The whole name of the MYOPTIONS contains the embedding class name.

Comment: just noticed that you were the first one to answer, thanks : )

Comment: IntelliJ says: modifier static is redundant for inner enums.  
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253226/nested-java-enum-definition-does-declaring-as-static-make-a-difference

Answer (score 2):

The declaration is valid, but you have to use it in this way:

```
Foo.MYOPTIONS var = Foo.MYOPTIONS.OPTION1
```

You are missing the name of the class when you are using the "enum".

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
Foo f = ...;
f.temp = Foo.MYOPTIONS.OPTION1;
```

Although I also would recommend to externalise `MYOPTIONS`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to refer to `Foo` when using the `MYPOTIONS` enum:

```java
public class Uta {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.temp = Foo.MYOPTIONS.OPTION1;
    }
}
```

Assuming that the class `Foo` is in package `foo` (you should always organize [classes in packages](http://www.jarticles.com/package/package_eng.html)), then you can also use [static imports](http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20060211/index.html), to make your code a bit cleaner:

```java
package foo;

import static foo.Foo.MYOPTIONS.OPTION1;

public class Uta {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.temp = OPTION1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Internally every enum constant return the object of type enum;(i.e Foo.MYOPTIONS.OPTION1 returns object of type MYOPTIONS) so we cant make our own intantiation(i.e new Foo.MYOPTIONS(); not allowed to create enum object explicitly becoz of num itself provide the object)

so, if we want to print reference variable by default .toString(); method will be invoked. In enum toString(); mehod overidden and its return the name of the constant. so we can have both Object and enum constant by one line 
(i.e Foo.MYOPTIONS.OPTION1)
example:

```
    class Foo {
        MYOPTIONS temp;

        public static enum MYOPTIONS {
            OPTION1, OPTION2, OPTION3;
        } 
    }

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo=new Foo();
        foo.temp = Foo.MYOPTIONS.OPTION1;
        System.out.println(foo.temp);
    }
}
```

that's it,if you write this line to instantiate enum object explicitly

(foo.temp = new Foo.MYOPTIONS();)

```
enter code here
```

you can get compile time error like:--

error: enum types may not be instantiated