# Why strange naming convention of "AlertDialog.Builder" instead of "AlertDialogBuilder" in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Why not

```
AlertDialogBuilder builder = new  AlertDialogBuilder(this);
builder.setTitle("foo");
```

instead of

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new  AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("foo");
```

**Update: I want to know the reason behind this kind of writing/organization**

Comment: I was going to post an answer but I think this one answers this question fully. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1953567/1286667

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Builder** is the static inner class inside the **AlertDialog** class. So to create a **Builder** class object, you need to call **AlertDialog.Builder**.

As there is no class like **AlertDialogBuilder** so you cannot do that.

If you want you can also use as like bellow.

```
Builder builder = new Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("foo");
```

But to use like this you need to import the **Builder** class to your class like

```
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
```

instead of just

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
```

A simple example

```
class A{
     static class B{}
}
```

you cannot use

```
AB obj = new AB();
```

you have to use

```
A.B obj = new A.B();
```

Hope you are clear now.

Comment: Are there any design considerations behind this? This design pattern is rare and I never use in other Java SDK.

Comment: I see only 2 benefits of using builders:
1) helps avoid constructors with many parameters.
2) helps avoid lots of data validation and allows to move it into single method called `build`.

Answer (score 25):

According to the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html), nested classes (and in this case, static nested classes) are generally used for three things:

1. Logically grouping classes which will only ever be used together.
2. Increasing encapsulation.
3. Increasing readability and maintainability of code.

Point #3 is one reason a lot of developers use static nested classes. Let's take, for example, the [`ViewHolder` pattern](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/viewholder-pattern-caching-view-efficiently/) in Android development. In a `ListAdapter`, we can make caching of lists easy by managing the contents of each list element in a `ViewHolder` (or similarly named inner class). In this situation, it is easy to notice that this specific `ViewHolder` is only for this class, and when we change this one, we don't change every single one. This means we don't need a `List1ViewHolder`, `List2ViewHolder`, ..., `ListNViewHolder`. Each `List`-type element can have its own `ViewHolder`.

Point #2 is a bit less relevant to this point, because we're dealing with static inner classes (that's what `Builder` is). But in this case, it prevents elements of the inner class from being accessed by the outer class.

Point #1 is the big one here, which is why I've saved it for last. Think of the situations in which you will use `AlertDialog.Builder`. I can guarantee, with 100% certainty, that every single time you use `AlertDialog.Builder`, it will be in the building/creation/handling of an `AlertDialog`. Consequently, this means that every use of `AlertDialog.Builder` is tied to how `AlertDialog` works. (This ties in somewhat with point #3; it's easier to maintain two classes in one file than to have them separated.)

Similar to points #1 and #3, but also of its own rite, is the fact that by keeping `Builder` within `AlertDialog`, we are not polluting the `android.app` package namespace. We still keep just `AlertDialog` within it; but `Builder` hides within that.

Android is not the only system that does this; the [MotiveWave SDK](http://support.motivewave.com/sdk/) does this also, as do the Adobe Access and eBay SDKs (which I lack links for). I also believe [Java EE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html) uses this methodology as well. You will also [see it often in Enum types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253226/nested-java-enum-definition-does-declaring-as-static-make-a-difference), which in turn is because of the reasons covered in point #1.

Now, you asked why we use `AlertDialog.Builder` instead of `new AlertDialog()`, and build it from the object instead of from the builder. The answer here is the same as the [factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) seen commonly in Java and other object-oriented programming languages. Notably (from Wikipedia), there are three reasons for this:

1. The creation of an object precludes its reuse without significant duplication of code.
2. The creation of an object requires access to information or resources that should not be contained within the composing class.
3. The lifetime management of the generated objects must be centralized to ensure a consistent behavior within the application.

These explain themselves pretty well; they speak against code duplication (being able to handle all creation functionality within one class), unauthorized access (bad encapsulation practices), and consistent behavior of construction. Also unlisted here is [code readability](https://stackoverflow.com/a/929193/1438733).

I suspect--on a hunch--that `AlertDialog` is a very resource-intense process. It halts parts of the OS, keeps others running, has to load system resources, and so on. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/929045/1438733) details, we do not want to provide direct access to the outer class (`AlertDialog` in this case). This allows the `Builder` to handle all resource-intensive operations properly. It also keeps us from having to handle esoteric situations which the OS developers considered, but we did not.

So, to conclude, this is actually a decently common design pattern, but not one that has a real explicitly defined meaning. Rather, it is for ease of use, understanding, and maintainability. You mention a concern about design considerations above; I wouldn't worry too much on that. Just keep in mind that static inner classes should *always* be solely related to their outer class, and you should be fine.

Comment: So why not just design as `AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog();` ?

Comment: It's for a few purposes, notably preventing bad access and handling resources in the best way possible. I've detailed this in my answer.

Comment: @Howard new AlertDialog() will lack any meaning having no title, no message, no anything. But then you don't have to set everything (e.g. you often don't need more than 1 button). So, the Builder pattern lets you specify what you need and nothing else and then lets you create() the dialog. It's a classic Builder Pattern case from the GoF book.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try and clear you up behind this kind of organization.

First of all, Builder is a class inside the AlertDialog class. 
Why would you create a class inside another class? I personally only create nested classes if I want to add more functionality to an existing class and don't believe that from a designing point of view that the class should be extended. I'm sure one could argue about this one, since there are tons of different ways to add more functionality to a class; yet nested classes can be preferred above others (for some people).

Here's [oracles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) point of view on nested classes.

I'd only use nested classes if I find that it makes the code more maintainable and intuitive.

In this case I believe the guys over at Google found that instead of creating a new class called AlertDialogBuilder compared to AlertDialog.Builder, is because both yield the same results; a dialog displaying some information on the screen with some buttons. The only difference between both (I think) is that you can set positive, neutral and negative button on the AlertDialog.Builder (which gives more functionality to the class, yet not necessary more that the class should be extended, again personal opinion).

In the end what matters is that the code works (hopefully without any bugs), is maintainable, readable and intuitive. There's no definite answer to your question, since people have different opinions on this topic.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The approach used to construct `AlertDialog` Object is called Builder Pattern to enhance readability. When you want to construct a new object but this object requires a lot of properties to create it like too many parameters (more than 4) passing to constructor you will got confused . If you want to know more about builder pattern I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1953567/1304187) will satisfy your needs. AlertDialog construction is quite similar to the example in the link :

```
@Override 
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
           .setMessage("Do you really want to exit?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setNegativeButton("No", 
                    new DaialogInterface.onClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, 
                            int id) {
                                    ((AlertDialogActivity) getActivity())
                                                .continueShutdown(false);
                                }

                        })
           .setPositibeButton("Yes", 
                    new DialogInterface.onClickListener()) {
                        public void onClick(
                                final DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    ((AlertDialogActivity) getActivity())
                                                .continueShutdown(true);
                                }
                    }).onCreate();
}
```

This method return Dialog object that asks user if he/she wants to exit the application as you can see it doesn't make any sense to create an AlertDialog object by calling a constructor with too many arguments. Imagine if `AlertDialog` has such a constructor :

```
AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog(getActivity(), "Do you really want to exit?", 
                                 false, "No", .... )//and the list goes on
```

Compare this approach with `onCreateDialog` method I think `onCreateDialog` method wins right ?