# Why have public static class inside a class

Tags: java, nested-class

I was going through some code and I saw this:

```
public class A {
    public A(SomeObject obj) {
      //Do something
    }
    //Some stuff
  public static class B {
    //Some other stuff
  }
}
```

I was wondering since even the inner class is `public` why have it as nested and not a separate class?
Also, can I do this here: `new A.B(SomeObject)` ? I feel this defeats the purpose of a static class but I saw this implementation as well so wanted to know.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I was wondering since even the inner class is public why have it as nested and not a separate class?

That's really a matter to ask whoever wrote the class. It can allow the outer class to act as a "mini-namespace" though - if the nested class is *only* useful in the context of the outer class, it seems reasonable. It indicates deliberate tight coupling between the two classes. I most often see this in the context of the builder pattern:

```
Foo foo = new Foo.Builder().setBar(10).build();
```

Here it makes sense to me to have `Foo.Builder` nested within `Foo` rather than as a peer class which would presumably be called `FooBuilder`.

Note that it also gives some visibility differences compared with just unrelated classes.

> Also, can I do this here: `new A.B(SomeObject)` ?

No, because `B` doesn't have a constructor with a `SomeObject` parameter - only `A` does (in the example you've given).

> I feel this defeats the purpose of a static class

You should try to work out *exactly* what you deem the purpose of a static class to be, and in what way this defeats that purpose. Currently that's too vague a statement to be realistically discussed.

Answer (score 5):

You would have an inner class like this so

- you can keep an class which only exists to support the outer class encapsulated.
- you want to be able to access `private` members of the outer class or other nested classes.
- you want a nested class with static fields (a weak reason I know ;)
- you have a class with a very generic name like `Lock` or `Sync` which you wouldn't want to be mixed with other classes of the same name used by classes in the same package.

> can I do this here: new A.B(SomeObject) ?

You can.

> I feel this defeats the purpose of a static class

It takes getting used to but once you start you may have trouble not turning your entire program into one file.java ;)

Answer (score 2):

**I was wondering since even the inner class is public why have it as nested and not a separate class?**

Have a look at this thread: [Why strange naming convention of "AlertDialog.Builder" instead of "AlertDialogBuilder" in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810345/why-strange-namimg-convention-of-alertdialog-builder-instead-of-alertdialogbu/11976021#11976021)

**Also, can I do this here: new A.B(SomeObject) ?**

*(Update)* No, you can't do this, since B doesn't have a constructor that asks for SomeObject.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your link currently points to the last answer. I would suggest this link instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810345/why-strange-namimg-convention-of-alertdialog-builder-instead-of-alertdialogbu

Comment: I think your answer is wrong for the `new A.B(SomeObject)` according to the other answers given below, which actually makes sense as there is no constructor for the static class

Answer (score 2):

**1.** A `static inner` class is known as `Top-Level` Class.

**2.** This `static class` has **direct access** to the Its Outer class **Static method and variables.**

**3.** You will need to initialize the `static Inner class` in this way from Outside...

```
    A a = new A();
    A.B b = new A.B();
```

**4.**   `new A.B(SomeObject)` **won't work**... because you **don't have a constructor** with `SomeObject` as parameter...

**5.** But when the Inner class is Non-static, then it have implicit reference to the Outer class.

**6.** The outer and inner class can **extends to  different classes**.

**7.** An `interface's method` can be implemented **more than once** in different or same ways, using Inner Class.

Answer (score 2):

This pattern is used very often with the builder pattern. It not only makes clear the relation between a class and its builder, but also hides the ugly builder constructor/factory and makes builder more readable. For example in case you need your built object to have optional and not optional properties.

```
public class AnObject {
   public static class AnObjectBuilder {

       private AnObject anObject;

       private AnObjectBuilder() {
       }

       private void newAnObjectWithMandatory(String someMandatoryField, ...) {
           anObject = new AnObject(someMandatoryField,...)
       }

       public AnObjectBuilder withSomeOptionalField(String opt) {
           ...
       }
   }

   public static AnObjectBuilder fooObject() {
        return (new AnObjectBuilder()).newAnObjectWithMandatory("foo")
   }

   public static AnObjectBuilder barObject() {
        return (new AnObjectBuilder()).newAnObjectWithMandatory("bar")
   }
}
```

This way the client code have to call first the static method on the `AnObjectBuilder` class and then to use the optional builder methods:

`AnObject.fooObject("foo").withSomeOptionalField("xxx").build();` without creating the builder object.

Pretty readable :)

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering since even the inner class is public why have it as
>   nested and not a separate class?

The simple reason it is allowed is packaging convenience.

[Static nested class in Java, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253492/static-nested-class-in-java-why)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

yes, you can do new `A.B(SomeObject)`. But you don't have to take my word for it, try it out.