# Why does Java disallow switch on static enums?

Tags: java, static, enums, switch-statement

I have to work with a library that defines an enum like this:

```
public static enum LibVal {
    VAL_1,
    VAL_2,
    VAL_3;
}
```

I get this enum as a method argument:

```
public void libCallback(LibVal val){
    //.... some implementation
}
```

Why does Java disallow the use of `switch` with the `LibVal` enum inside the `libCallback` method? However, if the lib had declared its enum as non-static it would work. This is confusing as this [SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253226/nested-java-enum-definition-does-declaring-as-static-make-a-difference) states, that there is really no difference...

Edit:

As bobkilla Stated: I tried LibVal.VAL_1 inside my switch, which should be allowed.
I provide a code-sample which wouldn't work!

```
class TestClassForEnum {
    public static enum TestEnum{ ONE, TWO; }
}

class WhichUsesEnumInsideMethod{

    //completely unrelated to TestClassForEnum.TestEnum!!!
    public static final int ONE = 0x1282

    void doSomethingWithEnum(TestEnum e){
        //here I cannot switch:

        //FORBIDDEN BY JAVA
        switch (e) {
            case TestEnum.ONE:
                    //...

        }

        //Cannot USE EITHER, because ONE is a static final int inside this scope?!:
        switch (e) {
            case ONE:
                    //...

        }

 }
```

Comment: show how you are trying to `switch`.

Comment: What is the compilation error ?

Comment: It doesn't disallow it. No evidence presented. Not a real question.

Comment: @EJP sorry I was in a hurry. I updated my question to provide evidence

Answer (score 5):

this will not work :

```
switch(val) {
            case LibVal.VAL_1: System.out.println("VAL_1 was chosen");
        }
```

this will work :

```
switch(val) {
            case VAL_1: System.out.println("VAL_1 was chosen");
        }
```

Comment: oh You are right. I tried `LibVal.VAL_1` which is not working. do You know why I'm not allowed to prefix it with LibVal?

Comment: I don't know why, I just know it will not compile if you use the prefix. And for your 'ONE' problem, i think it is because ONE is a static final int in this scope.

Comment: yes of course it is. Thats Why I initially thought, that I cannot switch over an enum at all...

Answer (score 2):

All enum are static by default and there is no difference.  You can switch on any enum, whether you make it static or not.

See this example here http://ideone.com/n5oQoi

```
public class Main {
    public static enum LibVal {
        VAL_1,
        VAL_2,
        VAL_3;
    }

    public void libCallback(LibVal val){
        switch(val) {
            case VAL_1: System.out.println("VAL_1 was chosen");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] ignored) {
        new Main().libCallback(LibVal.VAL_1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// your method signature:
public void libCallback(LibVal val){
    switch (val) {
    case VAL_1: System.out.println("It"); break;
    case VAL_2: System.out.println("works"); break;
    case VAL_3: System.out.println("fine"); break;
    default:    System.out.println("here.");
    }
}
```